# how to check for null with a ng-if values in a view with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, isnull

i have this situation

```
<div ng-repeat="test in current">
    <div ng-if="test.view == null">
        <i class="icon ion-checkmark"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

but `test.view== null` doesn't work, neither just checking for `test.view` or `test.view == ''`

any ideas?

thanks

edit:

in the loop, sometimes `test.view`, has a value sometimes is NULL if i do:

```
<div ng-if="!test.view">1</div>
<div ng-if="test.view">2</div>
```

i will only see `1`

Comment: are you confusing the test in your ng-repeat with a test variable on your scope? otherwise, you don't need to check for it because test isn't going to render if current is empty.

Comment: i changed the example a bit. now i have `test.view == null`

Comment: I don't understand.. your code shows `test.view == null` but the context of your problem below says `test == null` doesn't work. Please clarify your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830035/angularjs-ng-if-checking-model-value-but-model-value-of-input-set-only-if-inpu

Comment: also, null doesn't evaluate to falsey like you probably expect.

Comment: How can this be used when the boolean value is null.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should check for `!test`, here is [a fiddle showing that](http://jsfiddle.net/4KAJg/).

```
<span ng-if="!test">null</span>
```

Comment: Add the code to your example please, so developers can quickly see the code answer :-)

Comment: In your example there might be a problem if the array has 0 in it... :)

Comment: Thanks! If you don't want to include zeroes, then `ng-if="!test && test != 0"` would work. I'm not sure if there's a better way, though.

Comment: the issue with this is that " $scope.current = [1, null, 0];" will render "0 and null"

Answer (score 28):

See the correct way with your example:

```
<div ng-if="!test.view">1</div>
<div ng-if="!!test.view">2</div>
```

Regards, Nicholls

Comment: tried this in angular 2 using *ngIf but its not working

Comment: it's only to Angular 1 :)

Comment: This won't handle a zero value

Comment: @BryantJackson you're right, with numbers he needs to validate the type too

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ng-template, I think that would be more efficient while run time :)

```
<div ng-if="!test.view; else somethingElse">1</div>
<ng-template #somethingElse>
    <div>2</div>
</ng-template>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that I tried to explain.

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="product">     <!--If "product" exists-->
      <h2>Product Details</h2><hr>
      <h4>Name: {{ product.name }}</h4>
      <h5>Price: {{ product.price | currency }}</h5>
      <p> Description: {{ product.description }}</p>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="!product">     <!--If "product" not exists-->
       *Product not found
    </div>
</div>
```